# Using API_KEY Google Maps in Delphi application for computer

Tags: delphi, api-key

I've created an application in Delphi for a computer where the user can track their deliverers using the Google Maps API (api version 3). The browser used is the TChromium - for Delphi component that replaces the TWebBrowser.

So far so good, I've generated my API_KEY key and everything works fine. But my question is: And when do I sell my application? Will my client use this same key? Or should you create a key for it?

I say this because I do not know how I will control my share of API access. Since, as I understand it, it is limited to a certain amount of access per day, after that, a value will have to be paid to Google.

Example: If I sell 100 copies of my application, I can not know how many hits will be done in the 24-hour period ...

Had I misunderstood? Is anyone going through this?

Comment: It seems each customer would need their own, given the number of limited calls. I wrote a system which wraps many different weather API's in a standardized structure, and require that anyone who wants to use it get their own key. I can't imagine any good reason why you would want all your clients to use the same key.

Comment: On the other hand, if you are *selling* your application, and especially if it's being sold to people who are *not* developers, then you should consider having your own key. Not completely sure without researching, but I would think there should be a paid option if you intend to go over your limit. Also, most of the time, API's with limits like that are typically for development *only*, and they expect you to purchase a key for real usage.

Comment: First, you need to abide by Google's licensing terms.. it's not a free service when used with commercial applications. Each customer will need their own key https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: Hi.
Thank you.
I do not want them to use my key,
Instead, I want to know if I can create a key for every buyer on my system.

I do not know if the API captures the ID of my application for control ... I do not know if my APP can use multiple key_api ... (on different clients)

Comment: @Valdomiro  You should contact Google directly and they will help set you up with a plan. You might be able to create one key, or many keys.. but usually the moment you want to go commercial, it's a good idea to discuss it with them directly.

Comment: Your question did not ask that. Your question asked whether or not your customers should acquire their own key. If you want to know *how* to generate a key for each customer, that's a completely different question, which as @John said, you'll need to consult directly with Google. Chances are, they'll quote you a special price or agreement to match your specific usage.

Comment: Contact Google with questions regarding licensing and use of their API in your commercial application. This isn't Google licensing support, and there are legal implications to your question that are not appropriate here. Google and an attorney licensed in your jurisdiction are the only ones that can properly address what you can and can't do with the API.